# Display two generated tiles on one map using Openlayers

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, tiles, openlayers-2, display

i have a multiple Geo-referenced  tiff

I want to display Two TMS layer on one map.

in another way i want to display tow tailed tiff image in the same map like the picture bellow using  Openlayers and without any cartography server .

i tried all what i can do but without any result,
I'm still working on it please I'm looking for somebody to help me

this is explanation (for problem ):

[image]

**this is  a screen shot from QGIS desktop (showing tow images in the same time).**

---

**PROBLEM**

I'm working on a mobile application using cordova + OpenLayers-2.13.1
- the application must work off line no cartography server so i choose to use tiles, for this i used Maptiler 1.0 Beta 2 (open source)

i created tiles for each image :

[image]

this is the result :

[image]

each images was generated in a folder and has it code html+ JavaScript page for display

[image]

**code source generated for the first page   :**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>"
          <head>
            <title>MAP_1A_2_1.TIF</title>
            <meta http-equiv='imagetoolbar' content='no'/>
            <style type="text/css"> v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
                html, body { overflow: hidden; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Geneva,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif; }
                body { margin: 10px; background: #fff; }
                h1 { margin: 0; padding: 6px; border:0; font-size: 20pt; }
                #header { height: 43px; padding: 0; background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #888; }
                #subheader { height: 12px; text-align: right; font-size: 10px; color: #555;}
                #map { height: 95%; border: 1px solid #888; }
            </style>
            <script src='http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.1'></script>
            <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/2.7/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var map;
                var mapBounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds( -8.32551889184, 32.8485573951, -8.27061152288, 32.8948926537);
                var mapMinZoom = 12;
                var mapMaxZoom = 20;
    //var mapexb =new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508, 20037508, 20037508.34);

                // avoid pink tiles
                OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
                OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadErrorColor = "transparent";

                function init(){
                var options = {
                    controls: [],
                    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    units: "m",
                    maxResolution: 156543.0339,
                    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508, 20037508, 20037508.34)
                    };

    //               (203016.74715410196, 1894235.01319894, 3055035.146019727, 4007565.9708489403)


                map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);



                // create Virtual Earth layers
                OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth.prototype.MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL=19;
                OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth.prototype.RESOLUTIONS=OpenLayers.Layer.Google.prototype.RESOLUTIONS
                var veroad = new OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth("Virtual Earth Roads",
                    {'type': VEMapStyle.Road, 'sphericalMercator': true, numZoomLevels: 20});
                var veaer = new OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth("Virtual Earth Aerial",
                    {'type': VEMapStyle.Aerial, 'sphericalMercator': true, numZoomLevels: 20 });
                var vehyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth("Virtual Earth Hybrid",
                    {'type': VEMapStyle.Hybrid, 'sphericalMercator': true});


                // create OSM/OAM layer
                var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "OpenStreetMap",
                    "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/",
                    { type: 'png', getURL: osm_getTileURL, displayOutsideMaxExtent: true, 
                      attribution: '<a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>'} );


                // create TMS Overlay layer
                var tmsoverlay = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "TMS Overlay", "",
                    {   // url: '', serviceVersion: '.', layername: '.',
                        type: 'png', getURL: overlay_getTileURL, alpha: true, 
                        isBaseLayer: false
                    });
                if (OpenLayers.Util.alphaHack() == false) { tmsoverlay.setOpacity(0.7); }

                map.addLayers([veaer,veroad,  vehyb, tmsoverlay]);

                var switcherControl = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
                map.addControl(switcherControl);
                switcherControl.maximizeControl();

                map.zoomToExtent( mapBounds.transform(map.displayProjection, map.projection ) );

                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MouseDefaults());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults());
            }


            function overlay_getTileURL(bounds) {
                var res = this.map.getResolution();
                var x = Math.round((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
                var y = Math.round((bounds.bottom - this.tileOrigin.lat) / (res * this.tileSize.h));
                var z = this.map.getZoom();
                if (this.map.baseLayer.name == 'Virtual Earth Roads' || this.map.baseLayer.name == 'Virtual Earth Aerial' || this.map.baseLayer.name == 'Virtual Earth Hybrid') {
                   z = z + 1;
                }
                if (mapBounds.intersectsBounds( bounds ) && z >= mapMinZoom && z <= mapMaxZoom ) {
                   //console.log( this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type);
                   return this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
                } else {
                   return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
                }
            }       

           function getWindowHeight() {
                if (self.innerHeight) return self.innerHeight;
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
                    return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
                if (document.body) return document.body.clientHeight;
                    return 0;
            }

            function getWindowWidth() {
                if (self.innerWidth) return self.innerWidth;
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth)
                    return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                if (document.body) return document.body.clientWidth;
                    return 0;
            }

            function resize() {  
                var map = document.getElementById("map");  
                var header = document.getElementById("header");  
                var subheader = document.getElementById("subheader");  
                map.style.height = (getWindowHeight()-80) + "px";
                map.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
                header.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
                subheader.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
                if (map.updateSize) { map.updateSize(); };
            } 

            onresize=function(){ resize(); };

            </script>
          </head>
          <body onload="init()">
            <div id="header"><h1>MAP_1A_2_1.TIF</h1></div>
            <div id="subheader">Generated by <a href="http://www.maptiler.org/">MapTiler</a>/<a href="http://www.klokan.cz/projects/gdal2tiles/">GDAL2Tiles</a>, Copyright &copy; 2008 <a href="http://www.klokan.cz/">Klokan Petr Pridal</a>,  <a href="http://www.gdal.org/">GDAL</a> &amp; <a href="http://www.osgeo.org/">OSGeo</a> <a href="http://code.google.com/soc/">GSoC</a>
            <!-- LET THIS NOTE ABOUT AUTHOR AND PROJECT SOMEWHERE ON YOUR WEBSITE, OR AT LEAST IN THE COMMENT IN HTML. -->
            </div>
            <div id="map"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" >resize()</script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

---

### **this is the second page :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>"
          <head>
            <title>MAP_1A_1_1.TIF</title>
            <meta http-equiv='imagetoolbar' content='no'/>
            <style type="text/css"> v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
                html, body { overflow: hidden; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Geneva,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif; }
                body { margin: 10px; background: #fff; }
                h1 { margin: 0; padding: 6px; border:0; font-size: 20pt; }
                #header { height: 43px; padding: 0; background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #888; }
                #subheader { height: 12px; text-align: right; font-size: 10px; color: #555;}
                #map { height: 95%; border: 1px solid #888; }
            </style>
            <script src='http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.1'></script>

            <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/2.7/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var map;
                var mapBounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds( -8.37895410917, 32.8472818813, -8.32402054588, 32.8936399057);
                var mapMinZoom = 12;
                var mapMaxZoom = 18;

                // avoid pink tiles
                OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
                OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadErrorColor = "transparent";

                function init(){
                var options = {
                    controls: [],
                    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    units: "m",
                    maxResolution: 156543.0339,
                    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508, 20037508, 20037508.34)

                    };
                map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);


//{ -2969425.6743281255,  2411741.1161562973,  1090909.2674531247,  4322055.326717235}
                // create Virtual Earth layers
                OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth.prototype.MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL=18;
                OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth.prototype.RESOLUTIONS=OpenLayers.Layer.Google.prototype.RESOLUTIONS
                var veroad = new OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth("Virtual Earth Roads",
                    {'type': VEMapStyle.Road, 'sphericalMercator': true, numZoomLevels: 20});
                var veaer = new OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth("Virtual Earth Aerial",
                    {'type': VEMapStyle.Aerial, 'sphericalMercator': true, numZoomLevels: 20 });
                var vehyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.VirtualEarth("Virtual Earth Hybrid",
                    {'type': VEMapStyle.Hybrid, 'sphericalMercator': true});



                // create OSM/OAM layer
                var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "OpenStreetMap",
                    "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/",
                    { type: 'png', getURL: osm_getTileURL, displayOutsideMaxExtent: true, 
                      attribution: '<a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>'} );

                // create TMS Overlay layer
                var tmsoverlay = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "TMS Overlay", "",
                    {   // url: '', serviceVersion: '.', layername: '.',
                        type: 'png', getURL: overlay_getTileURL, alpha: true, 
                        isBaseLayer: false,
                        transparent:true,
                    });
                if (OpenLayers.Util.alphaHack() == false) { tmsoverlay.setOpacity(0.7); }

                map.addLayers([ veroad, veaer, vehyb, osm, tmsoverlay]);

                var switcherControl = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
                map.addControl(switcherControl);
                switcherControl.maximizeControl();

                map.zoomToExtent( mapBounds.transform(map.displayProjection, map.projection ) );

                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MouseDefaults());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults());
            }

            function osm_getTileURL(bounds) {
                var res = this.map.getResolution();
                var x = Math.round((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
                var y = Math.round((this.maxExtent.top - bounds.top) / (res * this.tileSize.h));
                var z = this.map.getZoom();
                var limit = Math.pow(2, z);

                if (y < 0 || y >= limit) {
                    return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
                } else {
                    x = ((x % limit) + limit) % limit;
                    return this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
                }
            }

            function overlay_getTileURL(bounds) {
                var res = this.map.getResolution();
                var x = Math.round((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
                var y = Math.round((bounds.bottom - this.tileOrigin.lat) / (res * this.tileSize.h));
                var z = this.map.getZoom();
                if (this.map.baseLayer.name == 'Virtual Earth Roads' || this.map.baseLayer.name == 'Virtual Earth Aerial' || this.map.baseLayer.name == 'Virtual Earth Hybrid') {
                   z = z + 1;
                }
                if (mapBounds.intersectsBounds( bounds ) && z >= mapMinZoom && z <= mapMaxZoom ) {
                   //console.log( this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type);
                   return this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
                } else {
                   return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
                }
            }       

           function getWindowHeight() {
                if (self.innerHeight) return self.innerHeight;
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
                    return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
                if (document.body) return document.body.clientHeight;
                    return 0;
            }

            function getWindowWidth() {
                if (self.innerWidth) return self.innerWidth;
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth)
                    return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                if (document.body) return document.body.clientWidth;
                    return 0;
            }

            function resize() {  
                var map = document.getElementById("map");  
                var header = document.getElementById("header");  
                var subheader = document.getElementById("subheader");  
                map.style.height = (getWindowHeight()-80) + "px";
                map.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
                header.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
                subheader.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
                if (map.updateSize) { map.updateSize(); };
            } 

            onresize=function(){ resize(); };

            </script>
          </head>
          <body onload="init()">
            <div id="header"><h1>MAP_1A_1_1.TIF</h1></div>
            <div id="subheader">Generated by <a href="http://www.maptiler.org/">MapTiler</a>/<a href="http://www.klokan.cz/projects/gdal2tiles/">GDAL2Tiles</a>, Copyright &copy; 2008 <a href="http://www.klokan.cz/">Klokan Petr Pridal</a>,  <a href="http://www.gdal.org/">GDAL</a> &amp; <a href="http://www.osgeo.org/">OSGeo</a> <a href="http://code.google.com/soc/">GSoC</a>
            <!-- LET THIS NOTE ABOUT AUTHOR AND PROJECT SOMEWHERE ON YOUR WEBSITE, OR AT LEAST IN THE COMMENT IN HTML. -->
            </div>
            <div id="map"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" >resize()</script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

---

**[Download Sample Data](http://41.248.245.93:81/sample/)**

**I'm Open if there is another way to do it**

Comment: I'm still unclear about your exact problem. Is the white border around the images you problem?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe thank you for your comment.  
so  the first image is a screen shot from  QGIS desktop and i want to do the same thing using Openlayers. 
for example i have tow tailed image (tiff) and i want to show them in the same map  like the first image using openlayers and without any cartography server

Comment: Is it an option for you to combine the two tiffs into a vrt before tiling the whole in one go?

Comment: @AndreJ thank you for your comment , no cause if i want to add another one i have to combine all again and create tiles

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe i added sample Data

Answer (score 4):

I don't have Maptiler 1.0 Beta 2 to test with, so I'm making a couple of assumptions:

1. You have tiles in the XYZ format and not the TMS format. I'm making this assumption because your screenshot shows "Google Maps Compatible" selected
2. You are using Openlayer 2.x

What I would do is to put the the two folders in one main folder such as:

```
Map
 MAP_1A_1_1
 MAP_1A_2_1
 index.html
```

Then in the OpenLayers Code, I will Add Both the XYZ Layers like this:

```
var layer1=new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
            "MAP_1A_1_1", 
           "MAP_1A_1_1/${z}/${y}/${x}");

var layer2=new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
            "MAP_1A_2_1", 
           "MAP_1A_2_1/${z}/${y}/${x}");
```

I would then add the two layers to the map as such:
`map.addLayers([layer1, layer2]);`

And If you have a TMS tiles, then just use `OpenLayers.Layer.TMS` instead of `OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ`

Comment: This makes it slightly harder to update in the future than just a merge of the .tif files; but otherwise the most sensible solution, +1

Comment: Why is this hard to update?

Comment: Well, it's unlikely, but if you have fifty `.tif` layers, I think it'd be better just to combine them into one image before touching any client JS.

Comment: i added sample Data

Comment: i tested this solution  but without any result

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your detail requirement but one other way to fullfill this by putting two map in parallel load as below.

`<div id="mapTile1"></div>
 <div id="mapTile2"></div>`

& use base map as clone so one movement operation also affect other one....

Comment: the problem is that i want to display multi tailed tiff in the same map like the first screen shot taken from QGIS Desktop using only openlayer and without Cartography server for exemple each tailed tiff will be in a different overlay layer .. i wrote a sample from only tow images to simplify the problem but my goal  is to show  multiple tailed tiff in the same map

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just merging the `.geotiff` files into one (and then doing what you have already done)? [GDAL has the ability to do this](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/gdal-raster-merge.html):

```
gdal_merge.py image1.tif image2.tif -o merged.tif
```

If you're concerned about the need to add more `.geotiff` files, then you could write a bash script to merge all `.tif` files in a directory, and then run your MapTiler process. Then it'd just be a matter of dropping more images into that directory and running the script to update. Let me know if you want/need help with that part.

Comment: no cause if i want to add another one i have to merge all again and create tiles , I'm looking for solution that i can add folder tile and add the layer in the code

Comment: I don't think there is a solution that will just allow you to specify a folder in your JS just once. IMO this is the nearest to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is the QTiles-plugin, which will create map tiles from your current qgis project.